# Why does the VASP electronic step not stop after getting converged?

Tags: vasp, numerical-convergence

I have just implemented VASP code with Gamma K-point, POSCAR of 128-atom supercell and INCAR like this:

```
   ISTART = 2
   ISPIN  = 2
   ICHARG = 1
   MAGMOM = 2*3 27*4 3 2*4 64*0 29*0
   ISMEAR = 0
   SIGMA  = 0.05
   NELMIN = 3
   NELM   = 60
   EDIFF  = 1E-05
   ISIF   = 2
   NSW    = 60
   IBRION = 3
   POTIM  = 0.1
   EDIFFG =-E-02
```

The problem is when the electronic relaxation reaches EDIFF, the electronic step does not stop. I just wonder if there is any other convergence requirement needed to be reached so that the electronic relaxation step stops.
[image][image]

Answer (score 6):

It is not converged, it needs to hit `|-1E-5|` on the **fourth** and **fifth** column.  It gets close on the fifth column, but never quite makes it there.  The lowest I see is about `|-1.7E-5|`.  It seems to be struggling, if this isn't an optimized structure then you could lower `EDIFF` to `1E-4` or even `5E-4` for some initial steps...Or simply do not worry about it and continue on regardless, over time you will converge faster with each geometric step.

However, if this is a single point job then you might need to change to `ALGO=ALL` for more stable convergence or change mixing settings.

Comment: I set EDIFF  = 1E-05. I calculated another supercell using the same INCAR, POTCAR  and K-point, and it stopped when dE = -0.81824E-05 (in the second figure). So I think there may be another convergence requirement.

Comment: I used a unit of 0.1E-5 not 1E-5, it makes it easier to read the OSZICAR directly and think about it.  This being said, I will update my answer as I realized that my original though was likely incorrect.